# [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]EXECUTE permission denied on object 'GetPSRreportStock', database 'CGTSP_GET',

Tags: coldfusion

when i executed the   code taken freshly from VSS , the following was the error

[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]EXECUTE permission denied on object 'GetPSRreportStock', database 'CGTSP_GET',

```
90 :     <cfprocparam  type="in" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" dbvarname="@reportMonth"  value="#xxMDB#">
91 :     <cfprocparam  type="in" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" dbvarname="@orderBy"     value="#xxOBDB#">
92 :     **<cfprocresult name="xxResult">**
93 : </cfstoredproc>
```

Can I get some solace please.

Errors are killing me.

Comment: I think you just edited your question to have no information...

Answer (score 8):

The account that CF is using to access your SQL Server doesn't have permission to run that stored procedure.

Comment: i have admin access to SQL 2005 
and the CFserver is my Devsevert opn which i have been working since feww months.

Comment: @dan: An "access denied" error is unambiguous. Check your configuration (data sources in CF Administrator, ColdFusion ODBC Service account, SQL Server). I'm sure you find a glitch in there somewhere.

Comment: CFIDE is missing in my CF folder.

Comment: and I? cannot find the SQL stored procs, tables etc in my SQL DB

Comment: If you suddenly can't find anything in your database, either everything was deleted, or somehow your access has been revoked (more likely since you're getting the access denied error).

Comment: i had the data base showing corrupt message ,

DB was restarted and the error rectifyed.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the data source as defined in ColdFusion Administrator has specifically turned off Stored Procedures under "Allowed SQL". Check the advanced settings for that data source.

Comment: thanks Al . that's really nice information to know.I will do that.